# How to conditional display a control in asp wizard based on the radio button click in a particular step using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, aspwizard

I've been stuck with this problem where there are 3 steps in an asp wizard control. The first step has a radio button (yes and no) and based on the radio button input chosen by the user, I would need to hide or show a label in the second wizardstep.

Example:

Step 1: Choose 1 among the two options: Yes No (radStep1)

Step 2: if the radio button option in the previous step was yes.. then display a label(lblStep2) in this step.. Else hide the label.

I've been handling this through the jQuery as I want the functionality in the ASPX page itself...

The jQuery code goes like this...

```
$("#<%=radStep1.ClientID %> input").click(function() {
if($("#<%= radStep1.ClientID %> input").index(this) == 0)
{
     $("#<%=lblStep2.ClientID %>").show();
}
else if($("#<%= radStep1.ClientID %> input").index(this) == 1)
{
    $("#<%=lblStep2.ClientID %>").hide();
}
```

However, in both the cases, the label is getting displayed.. Could you please help me out if there is anything that I'm missing?

I'm guessing that the label is getting hidden at first and then getting shown again once I click on the next button...

Thanks a ton in advance....

Comment: If you are on the first step of the wizard, the second step is not rendered yet, so you cannot use javascript to manipulate it. Why dont you use the normal event handlers asp.net and hide the control from the code behind on postback?

Comment: Luis,

Thanks so much for responding to my question...

My application demands that i should not be having a codebehind after the potback... Is there a way wherein i could insert a html input button instead of the 'next' button which is provided by the asp:wizard on the first step and thereby write a function in jquery for $('#inpBtn").click()?